# iptables command from RHEL documentation for cobbler, fails in RHEL 7

Tags: iptables, rhel7, cobbler, satellite

This seems like a very simple question.  But I don't see anything much about it on the web.  The command comes from [the RHEL documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Network_Satellite/5.3/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-provisioning-kickstarting.html) itself, so I would expect that it works... and yet it fails.  Any insight?

**Command:**

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p udp --dport 25150 -j ACCEPT
```

**Output:**

```
iptables: Invalid argument. Run `dmesg' for more information.
```

**dmesg log:**

```
[ 1719.334534] x_tables: ip_tables: tcp match: only valid for protocol 6
```

Comment: thinking that it might be an error, I changed "-m tcp -p udp" to "-m tcp -p tcp" because it seems to make more sense.  I added a second entry with "-m udp -p udp" just in case.  I suppose I'll know if that broke things or fixed them when I attempt to use cobbler.  iptables did not choke when I created those rules...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Congratulations, you found an error in the RHEL documentation.

The iptables rule shown here uses the `tcp` matcher but then attempts to specify the `udp` protocol. This doesn't work; the `tcp` matcher can only be used with protocol 6, which happens to be `tcp`. Thus the error you received.

To correct the rule you have to first figure out which is wrong, the matcher or the protocol. Unfortunately this error has been propagated all over the Internet so this isn't so easy to figure out from an Internet search, and even the Cobbler documentation doesn't clearly mention it.

You can sort it out easily by inspecting the output of `ss -nl`, and there you should find cobbler listening on TCP port 25150, not UDP. Thus you replace `udp` with `tcp` and then report the documentation error to Red Hat.

Comment: I'd upvote ya, but I have no reputation...which is silly.  I appreciate your response.

Comment: It's hardly the first error I've seen in RHEL documentation, unfortunately.

Comment: @TommyButler you can still reward Michael by accepting his answer: click the tick outline next to it.

Comment: Thanks @MadHatter.  Just getting started here at SE and I appreciate the help.

Comment: No worries, Tommy; I appreciate both your courtesy and the quality of your first question (+1 from me!).  Keep it up!